# Popcorn-Time installation

Tags: software-installation, tar

I downloaded a new Popcorn Time from [popcorn-time.se](http://popcorn-time.se/) and I don't know how to install a tar.gz file. I extracted the folder that is in tar.gz and then tried to run command sudo ./install but there in no command found.. What should I do? How to install this "new" Popcorn Time source file?

Comment: See the answer  (http://askubuntu.com/questions/707425/installing-popcorn-time-on-bootable-usb-on-chromebook)

Answer (score 5):

Those are directly the files you need to run the program. For opening Popcorn Time, just run from the extracted folder:

```
./Popcorn-Time
```

---

However, if you want to know where to save all those files with the other programs, a good place would be `/usr/share`.
So, let's say the folder where you extracted the files is `~/popcorn-time`. Then, you'll have to run this in a terminal:

```
# Copy the whole folder into /usr/share, using recursive option
sudo cp -r ~/popcorn-time /usr/share/popcorn-time
# Create a symlink to the binary file
sudo ln -s /usr/share/popcorn-time/Popcorn-Time /usr/bin/popcorn-Time
```

From now on, you'll be able to run `popcorn-Time` on the Terminal, and it'll open.

Finally, if you want to have an icon in the launcher, create a new file in your home directory, named `popcorn.desktop`, and write the following in it:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Popcorn Time
Comment=Watch torrent movies instantly!
Exec=/usr/bin/popcorn-time
Terminal=false
Type=Application
```

Comment: Yes, but when i run ./Popcorn-Time i get this message: ./Popcorn-Time: error while loading shared libraries: libudev.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
What now?

Comment: Just install the required library with `sudo apt-get install libudev0:i386` and try again.

Comment: sudo apt-get install libudev0:i386
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package libudev0 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'libudev0' has no installation candidate

Comment: Manually download it ([x86](http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/u/udev/libudev0_175-0ubuntu9_i386.deb), [x64](http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/u/udev/libudev0_175-0ubuntu9_amd64.deb)), and install it with `sudo dpkg -i libudev0_175-0ubuntu9_*`. If any dependences errors appear, try after that `sudo apt-get install -f`.

Answer (score 2):

When you unpack it, that already is the installation. It's no source file, it's a binary precompiled proprietary blob.